# Как загрузить проект с github в среде go?

Tags: golang, github

Выложил проект на github, хочу сделать так, чтобы другие пользователи могли подгрузить проект с помощью команды go get, но в этом случае выдает ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить структуру проекта, чтобы пользователи могли загрузить проект с помощью команды go get?

Ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/g0Influencer/BookStore.git

Comment: У вас в `go.mod` написано `module file-share`, а должно быть `module github.com/g0Influencer/BookStore`.

Comment: @PakUula спасибо, помогло

Comment: Что делает этот проект, для чего он?